# Generating a 2-D table of results in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a list of items that is refreshed daily where each item falls into one of four price bands.

The following query will pull the counts of items in each price band by date, but it puts each band/date combination into its own row.

```
SELECT PB.band, Count(L.ID) as Count
FROM ListItem L
join PriceBand PB on L.price >= PB.loprice and L.price <= PB.hiprice
Where ListID = 1  and ranking <= 100 and band >= 1 and band <= 4
Group by date, PB.band
order by date asc, band asc
```

The result set looks like this (two days used for illustration):

```
date    band    Count
2010-12-08  1   20
2010-12-08  2   17
2010-12-08  3   32
2010-12-08  4   26
2010-12-09  1   19
2010-12-09  2   16
2010-12-09  3   33
2010-12-09  4   27
```

While I can iterate through this to create the table I really want, is there a reasonable way to write the query to return the data in a 2-D form as follows:

```
date        band1   band2   band2   band3   
2010-12-08  20      17      32      26
2010-12-09  19      16      33      27
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT [date],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN PB.band = 1 THEN L.ID END) AS band1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN PB.band = 2 THEN L.ID END) AS band2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN PB.band = 3 THEN L.ID END) AS band3,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN PB.band = 4 THEN L.ID END) AS band4
FROM ListItem L
join PriceBand PB on L.price >= PB.loprice and L.price <= PB.hiprice
Where ListID = 1  and ranking <= 100 and band >= 1 and band <= 4
Group by date
order by date asc
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin.  100% perfect.  I wasn't familiar with CASE in SQL but I am now.

Answer (score 3):

Check out PIVOT clause in T-SQL. =>[MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

I'm not sure about the exact form of the query, but it should look something like this (please let me know if it works):

```
SELECT [date],[1],[2],[3],[4]
FROM ListItem L
join PriceBand PB on L.price >= PB.loprice and L.price <= PB.hiprice
Where ListID = 1  and ranking <= 100 and band >= 1 and band <= 4
PIVOT(COUNT(L.ID) FOR PB.band IN([1],[2],[3],[4])) as pvt   
order by [date] asc
```

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry.  This looks interesting as well, but Martin's answer was simple to implement and got me past the problem quickly.

Comment: Well, Martin's solution is good when you have only 4 bands. But it's good to know PIVOT too: you might need 10, 20 categories and it's quicker to write a pivot clause than 20 case clauses. I don't know about performance but I guess that PIVOT is also quicker. Downside -- PIVOT & UNPIVOT is for MSSQL >=2005 only.

Comment: BTW, if your ListItem can't belong to several bands (or to none) I think it'd be a good idea to remove hiprice from PriceBand and use next band's loprice as an upper bound. In your current configuration bands can overlap and there can be gaps between bands. (unless it's what you want, of course)

Answer (score 2):

First, "date" is a **horrible** name for a column, so I hope that's just an example. Second, since you didn't use an alias with it, I have no idea which table it's actually in, so here's my best guess:

```
SELECT
    LI.list_date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PB.band = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS band_1_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PB.band = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS band_2_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PB.band = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS band_3_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PB.band = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS band_4_count
FROM
    List_Item LI
INNER JOIN Price_Band PB ON
    PB.low_price <= LI.price AND
    PR.high_price >= LI.price AND
    PB.band <= 4
WHERE
    LI.list_id = 1 AND
    LI.ranking <= 100 AND
GROUP BY
    LI.list_date
ORDER BY
    LI.list_date
```

Comment: Agreed.  I was a little bit loose with syntax in this example.  Uptick for calling that out and the good formating.  It was COUNT, though, not SUM, but that's a nit.

Comment: SUM will work in this case, since I'm using 1 or 0 as the result of the CASE statement. Martin uses the L.ID column (or NULL if the row doesn't match the criteria), so COUNT works in that case.